# Can Internet data be used by malware when PC off?

Tags: wireless-networking, malware

I have noticed over the last month that my off peak data has been used at a rate of approx 350MB per hour - this has meant that I have gone over my quota and slowed down by my ISP to 256k. There is no one in the house using it (2am-8am is my ISPs off peak hours) at that time.

My PC and other wireless devices (ipad and iphone) are turned off. I have changed the wireless password on my modem 3 times and it is now 30 digits long. So I don't think someone else is using my wireless access between 2-8am. It has been suggested by my ISP that I may have malware/spyware on my computer.

Sorry for my ignorance, but can malware still run if the PC is off? I did look at my modem's log and followed an IP address to a service called Amazon Simple server Storage. Could this company possibly be the culprit? I am not too tech savvy, so any assistance appreciated. I have run a barrage of spyware cleaning software eg malware bytes; spy bot etc.

Comment: If the PC is turned off, then its turned off, the question does not make a great deal of sense.  Amaz Simple Service could be the culprit but but only if you have an Amazon account.  Its not malicious but if you didn't install the service uninstall it.

Comment: @Ramhound `If the PC is turned off, then its turned off` Well, unless someone's configured [`wakeonlan`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN). The NIC can still be on when the machine's CPU is turned off.

Comment: @ParthianShot - Then it would be turned on and the user would have pointed that out

Comment: @Ramhound I was making two points, and I admit they were jumbled. Point 1 was that the machine could have been on at times he didn't notice (e.g. using `wakeonlan`), but point 2 was that, if the machine was plugged in, peripherals other than the CPU could be running malicious firmware (e.g. the NIC), so the machine would technically be off (the power LED would be disengaged), but the machine would still be doing things.

Answer (score 0):

When a PC is turned off, no internet traffic is possible from that PC.

If your internet activity is still going on even though you are sure all your devices are not connected, then there can be the following problems:

1. Either, there still is a device connected to your wifi or wired connection that uses the internet
2. There's a second wifi connection you completely forgot/ignored (such as on a modem) that is being used by a third party
3. An external source keeps hacking your password. Note that WEP protection is not a good one. WPA2 is much stronger. If your device supports it, enable Hide SSID and change the name of your SSID. This will ensure that no one can connect unless they know the name.